# React Redux action object is undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am new to React-Redux and I have a problem with redux action object. When I am printing the object to the console, it displays correctly as shown below:
[image: shown below]

Please check my codes.

**FeedPage.jsx**

```
class FeedPage extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        const { id } = this.props.match.params;
        this.props.dispatch(feedActions.getById(id));
        console.log("props", this.props);
    }

    render() {
        const { user, feed } = this.props;

    ... 

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    const { feed, authentication } = state;
    const { user } = authentication;
    console.log(JSON.stringify(feed));
    return {
        user,
        feed
    };
}

const connectedFeedPage = connect(mapStateToProps)(FeedPage);
export { connectedFeedPage as FeedPage };
```

**reducer.js**

```
export function feeds(state = {}, action) {
switch (action.type) {
    case feedConstants.GETBYID_REQUEST:
    return {
        loading: true
    };
    case feedConstants.GETBYID_SUCCESS:
    console.log("GETBYID_SUCCESS: " + JSON.stringify(action.feed));
    return {
        feed: action.feed
    };
    case feedConstants.GETBYID_FAILURE:
    return { 
        error: action.error
    };

    ...
```

**service.js**

```
function getById(id) {
    const requestOptions = {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: authHeader()
    };

    return fetch(`${config.apiUrl}/feed/${id}`, requestOptions).then(handleResponse);
}
```

**actions.js**

```
function getById(id) {
    return dispatch => {
        dispatch(request());

        feedService.getById(id)
            .then(
                feed => dispatch(success(feed)),
                error => dispatch(failure(error.toString()))
            );
    };

    function request() { return { type: feedConstants.GETBYID_REQUEST } }
    function success(feed) { return { type: feedConstants.GETBYID_SUCCESS, feed } }
    function failure(error) { return { type: feedConstants.GETBYID_FAILURE, error } }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

**root reducer**

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';

import { authentication } from './authentication.reducer';
import { registration } from './registration.reducer';
import { users } from './users.reducer';
import { alert } from './alert.reducer';
import { feeds } from './feeds.reducer';

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    authentication,
    registration,
    users,
    alert,
    feeds
});

export default rootReducer;
```

This is the screenshot of the logs:

[image: logs]

So it is clear that feed object is not empty. But when I am referencing it, it is undefined. Please help as I am stuck and cannot move forward. Any help is great appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: please show your root reducer, I think I know what the problem might be...

Comment: @ChrisCousins posting now. Please check.

Comment: you're talking about referencing it in render method ? right

Comment: @SakhiMansoor yep you're right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your root reducer, you are saying that the item "feeds" will contain what your feedReducer gives it. In your feedReducer you return "feed: action.feed".

So, in your mapStateToProps, you should be mapping "feeds", not "feed". When you then read the feeds value, it will contain an object such as { feed: xxx } where xxx is what your action originally had in it after your API call.

Comment: Thanks for bringing this to my attention. However, I cannot access the property of feed. I tried doing this: feeds.feed.id but it's undefined.

Comment: What do you get when you console.log(feeds)? Also, please update the code in the question to reflect any changes to mapStateToProps etc.

Comment: {"feed":{"id":5,"description":"Latest update 5","created_by":{"id":10002,"first_name":"James","last_name":"Estrada"},"date_created":"2018-08-14T02:16:17.961Z","date_modified":"2018-08-14T02:16:17.961Z","modified_by":null}}

Comment: In your render function, it is entirely possible that your async feeds data hasn't arrived yet. Make sure in your render function, you check whether feeds has anything in it (for instance if(feeds.feed) { ... }) and if it doesn't, just return null from the render function.

Comment: yey that works! Thank you. Tried something like this: {
                                                                    feeds.feed ? feeds.feed.id : ''
                                                                    }

Comment: In my case I had this in rootReducer :) 
`import app from './reducer/auth'; import auth from './reducer/auth'; const rootReducer = combineReducers({auth, app}); export default rootReducer;`

and `app from './reducer/auth` was the issue

Answer (score 0):

There's an issue with your reducer. You're mutating component state as it store doesn't get updated when we mutate the state and component doesn't re render

```
case feedConstants.GETBYID_SUCCESS:
    console.log("GETBYID_SUCCESS: " + JSON.stringify(action.feed));
    return {
      ...state,
      feed: action.feed
    };
```

in your case Redux doesn't detect a difference in state and won't notify your components that the store has changed and you should return a new copy of state with the necessary change. Hope this would solve the issue
Let me know if the issue still persists.

Comment: and you can get updated state in `componentWillReceiveProps()` and you can setState there and your component will re render.