# React-Redux - Get User by ID

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

so I am trying to get a User from my redux store by only providing the user id.

My Code looks almost exactly like this one by bEtTy Barnes:

[React Redux action object is undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52011801/react-redux-action-object-is-undefined)

I am trying to paste the username inside the TopicCard component to topicBy but I only have the user_id. Thats why I want to call there this.handleUserByID(topics.topic_by) but it does not work. I also added some console.logs to show how the code behaves.

After the first fixes:
I get this error now:
react-dom.development.js:21 Warning: Cannot update a component ConnectFunction while rendering a different component KeyboardPage. To locate the bad setState() call inside `KeyboardPage`, follow the stack trace as described in
in KeyboardPage (created by ConnectFunction)
in ConnectFunction (created by Context.Consumer)
in Route (created by PrivateRoute)
in PrivateRoute (created by App)
in Switch (created by App)
in Router (created by App)
in div (created by App)
in div (created by App)
in div (created by App)
in App (created by ConnectFunction)
in ConnectFunction
in Provider

Edit: fixed this.props.getUser @handleUserByID but it still does not work
Edit topicBy

```
import React, {useEffect} from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

import {topicActions, userActions} from '../../../actions';

import NavBar from '../../NavBar/NavBar';
import TopicCard from "../../ContentCard/TopicCard/TopicCard";

class KeyboardPage extends React.Component {

componentDidMount() {
    this.props.getTopics(2);
}

handleUserByID(user_id){
   return this.props.getUser(user_id);
}

render() {

    const { topics } = this.props;
    const { user, users} = this.props;

    //console.log(this.props.getUser(1)) *Works but gets called multiple times and returns the correct user object
    console.log(this.handleUserByID(1)); * Doesnt work;

    return (
        <div className="container">
            <NavBar loggedinAs={user.user_name}/>
            <h1>Gruppe 1 - Webforum</h1>
            <h3>Topics :</h3>
            {topics.loading && <em>Loading topics...</em>}
            {topics.error && <span className="text-danger">ERROR: {topics.error}</span>}
            {topics.items && users.items &&
            <ul type='none' >
                {topics.items.map((topic, index) =>
                    <li key={topic.topic_id}>
                        <p/>
                        <a href={"/" + topic.topic_id} style={{ textDecoration: 'none' }}>
                            <TopicCard topicSubject={topic.topic_subject} topicDate={topic.topic_date} topicBy={this.handleUserByID(topic.topic_by).user_name}/>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                )}
            </ul>
            }

        </div>
    );
}
}



      function mapState(state) {
          const {topics } = state;
          const { users, authentication } = state;
          const { user, } = authentication;
          return { user, users, topics};
      }
    
      const actionCreators = {
         getTopics: topicActions.getAllbyID,
         getUser: userActions.getById
      }
    
      const connectedKeyboardPage = connect(mapState, actionCreators)(KeyboardPage);
      export { connectedKeyboardPage as KeyboardPage };
```

Comment: Maybe changing `this.getUser()` in `handleUserByID()` to `this.props.getUser()`?

Comment: you are right - but sadly it does not fix the problem

Comment: What does the `handleUserByID()` function return then?

Comment: When I use console.log(this.handleUserByID(1) I get this response: ƒ (e) {
        return _this.props.getUser(user_id);
      }

Comment: Ok, see my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

You are not calling handleUserByID from any where.

```js
import React, {useEffect} from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

import {topicActions, userActions} from '../../../actions';

import NavBar from '../../NavBar/NavBar';
import TopicCard from "../../ContentCard/TopicCard/TopicCard";

class KeyboardPage extends React.Component {

componentDidMount() {
    this.props.getTopics(2);
}

handleUserByID(user_id){
   return(e) => this.getUser(user_id);
}

render() {

    const { topics } = this.props;
    const { user, users} = this.props;

    //console.log(this.props.getUser(1)) *Works but gets called multiple times and returns the correct user object
    //console.log(this.handleUserByID(1)); * Doesnt work;

    return (
        <div className="container">
            <NavBar loggedinAs={user.user_name}/>
            <h1>Gruppe 1 - Webforum</h1>
            <h3>Topics :</h3>
            {topics.loading && <em>Loading topics...</em>}
            {topics.error && <span className="text-danger">ERROR: {topics.error}</span>}
            {topics.items && users.items &&
            <ul type='none' >
                {topics.items.map((topic, index) =>
                    <li key={topic.topic_id}>
                    onClick={()=> this.handleUserByID(topic.topic_id)}
                        <p/>
                        <a href={"/" + topic.topic_id} style={{ textDecoration: 'none' }}>
                            <TopicCard topicSubject={topic.topic_subject} topicDate={topic.topic_date} topicBy={topic.topic_by}/>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                )}
            </ul>
            }

        </div>
    );
}
}



      function mapState(state) {
          const {topics } = state;
          const { users, authentication } = state;
          const { user, } = authentication;
          return { user, users, topics};
      }
    
      const actionCreators = {
         getTopics: topicActions.getAllbyID,
         getUser: userActions.getById
      }
    
      const connectedKeyboardPage = connect(mapState, actionCreators)(KeyboardPage);
      export { connectedKeyboardPage as KeyboardPage };
```

Comment: I tried to call it in TopicCard @ topic_by={this.handleUserByID(topic.topic_by).user_name} but it does sadly nothing

Answer (score 0):

The error in this code lies in the way that you construct the `handleUserByID` function. Your code here creates a function that returns another function, through the use of an inline lambda:

```
// function
handleUserByID(user_id) {
   return (e) => this.props.getUser(user_id); // Same as () => {}, or a function f(e)
}
```

Since you are returning a function from `handleUserByID()`, to get the return value of `getUser(user_id)` you could do `this.handleUserByID(id)()`.

Alternatively, you could change the function to return a value:

```
handleUserByID(user_id){
   return this.props.getUser(user_id); // Returns value or User type
}
```

You could then call it as you already do:

```
console.log(this.handleUserByID(1)); //Prints the return of getUser(1)
```

Comment: Thanks alot for the fast answer.Sadly I get an error now I will edit the post with the message

Comment: Thanks for editing the message. I'm not sure how to solve your problem without more information. The new error seems to be something related to the greater code base. If you are unable to find a fix to the new error, I recommend you create a new question and include the extended relevant code.

Comment: Yeh I think I will delete this question and create a new one. Thanks alot for your help so far

Comment: I wouldn't delete this question, as it may help others experiencing a similar problem in the future. Feel free to copy as much as you like since it is the same code.